# The two moves attack

Tags: chess

From the chess starting setup position, the twins are playing White.

All regular rules are applied except:

- The Black player wins if he makes it to the 7th move
- Each twin makes a move, then black moves

How can the twins checkmate their opponent to win?

Comment: Black moves when the King is in check.

Comment: So, white has 2 moves for every black 1?

Comment: yes,when the first  white move is not a check

Comment: Does the checkmate condition account for white getting two moves in a row, or do the twins have to enter a position that would be checkmate under standard rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Targeting the weakest square (f7) is the quickest.

I have the following solutions, using standard algebraic notation, with white move 1, white move 2; black move

> 1. Nf3, Ne5; f6 (or f5)
>  2. e4, Qh5+; g6
>  3. Nxg6, Ne5#
>
>  If 1. ... Nh6 (to protect f7)
>  2. e4, Bc4; e6
>
>  If 2. ... d5, then 3. Bxd5, Bxf7, continuing as below,
>  while on 2. ... f6 (or f5), 3. Bf7+; Nxf7 4. Qh5, Qxf7#
>
>  3. Bxe6, Bxf7+; Nxf7
>  4. Qf3, Qxf7#
>
>  Blocking the diagonal first with 1. ... e6 gives us:
>  2. e4, Qh5; Nh6
>  3. Nxf7, Nxh6+ (or Nd6+); Ke7
>  4. e5, Qf7#
>
>  if 2. ... Ke7
>  3. Qxf7+; Kd6
>  4. Na3, Nac4+; Kc5
>  5. Qxe6, Qd5+; Kb4
>  6. Qa4#
>
>  1. ... g6 is no better, with play as in other lines.
>  2. e4, Bc4; Nh6
>
>  2. ... e6 allows 3. Qf3, Qxf7#
>
>  3. Qf3, Bxf7+; Nxf7
>  4. Qxf7+
>
>  While 1. ... d6, threatening the Knight, fails to
>  2. e4, Bb5+; Qd7
>  3. Qf3, Qxf7+; Kd8
>  4. Qxf8+; Qe8
>  5. Qxe8#
>
>  1. ... c6, trying to give the king an escape route
>  2. e4, Qf3; Qa5
>  3. Qxf7+; Kd8
>  4. Qxf8+; Kc7
>  5. Nf7, Qd8#

It appears the best black can do, is get mated at move 7.

> 1. Nf3, Ne5; Nc6
>  2. Nxc6, Ne5; e6, continuing as above.
>  3. e4, Qh5; Ke7
>  4. Qxf7+; Kd6
>  5. Na3, Nac4+; Kc5
>  6. Qxe6, Qd5+; Kb4
>  7. Qa4#
>
>  Or, with 3. ... Qe7, as OP suggests,
>  4. Nxf7, Nd6+; Kd8
>  5. d4, Nf7+; Ke8 (if Qxf7, 6. Qxf7, Qxf8#)
>  6. Bg5, Nd6+; Kd8
>  7. Qe8#

Comment: does that count as making it to move 7?

Comment: I assumed that black has to make it to their move 7.

Comment: From the last move line above,with queen guarding f7.. black might make it to 7th
1. Nf3, Ne5; Nc6
2. Nxc6, Ne5; e6, continuing as above.
3. e4, Qh5;Qe7(protecting f7)
4. d4,Bg5; g6 
5. Bxe7,Qf3; Nh6..
6. Bxf8,Bxh6;Rf8
7. Bxf8,Qxf7+;Kd8!

Comment: @TSLF White mates with 7. Qa3, Qxf8#. 6. ... f5 or f6 may be better for black. I'm still looking at it, though.

Comment: @Herb Wolfe-at 1st looks like theknight may be there too soon that it can threaten twice by black: 
1. Nf3, Ne5; Nc6
2. Nxc6, Ne5; d6
3. e4, Qh5;
but black cant take e5, 3..,..Be6..4. Bc4,Bxe6..